# inheritFromWidgetOfExactType not working for generic InheritedWidget

Tags: flutter, bloc

It seems like `inheritFromWidgetOfExactType` method cannot find `InheritedWidget` if the widget is child of generic `StatefulWidget` and is generic itself.

I'm using InheritedWidget to implement bloc pattern. Initial implementation of BlocProvider looks like this:

```
class BlocProvider<T extends BlocBase> extends InheritedWidget {
  final T bloc;

  const BlocProvider({
    Key key,
    @required this.bloc,
    @required Widget child,
  })
      : assert(bloc != null),
        assert(child != null),
        super(key: key, child: child);

  static T of<T extends BlocBase>(BuildContext context) {
    final type = _typeOf<BlocProvider<T>>();
    final provider = context.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(type) as BlocProvider<T>;
    print("provider: $provider");
    return provider.bloc;
  }

  static Type _typeOf<T>() => T;

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(BlocProvider old) => false;
}
```

It works ok if used directly:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      bloc: BlocTop(),
      child: BlocConsumer()
    );
  }
```

But I'd like to wrap the bloc provider with StatefulWidget so the bloc state is not rebuild every time widgets tree is rebuild.

```
class BlocHolder<T extends BlocBase> extends StatefulWidget { 

final Widget child;
  final T Function() createBloc;
  final bool wantKeepAlive;

  BlocHolder({
    @required this.child,
    this.createBloc,
    this.wantKeepAlive
  });

  @override
  _BlocHolderState createState() => _BlocHolderState();
}

class _BlocHolderState<T extends BlocBase>
    extends State<BlocHolder>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<BlocHolder> {

  T _bloc;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _bloc = widget.createBloc();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      child: widget.child,
      bloc: _bloc,
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _bloc?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => widget.wantKeepAlive ?? false;
}
```

Now, when I'm trying to use this pattern `inheritFromWidgetOfExactType` returns `null` instead of InheritedWidget:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocHolder(
      createBloc: () => BlocTop(),
      child: BlocConsumer()
    );
  }
```

Any way to overcome this issue? Note, that I'd like to be able to nest bloc providers using this approach.

Comment: You may want to let packages handle that kind of stuff instead of rewriting your own. The package [provider](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/provider) in its version 2.0-dev is becoming the official package to handle that kind of stuff

Answer (score 3):

My problem was not specifying generic type when creating state in BlocHolder. This line

```
@override
_BlocHolderState createState() => _BlocHolderState();
```

should be:

```
@override
_BlocHolderState<T> createState() => _BlocHolderState<T>();
```

Comment: thanks. it works in my case after following your suggestion